# Convert base 64 encoding string into image

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, base64, html2canvas

I want to convert base 64 encoding image png or jpeg image.

I want to convert into image and It must be save on server, It must be move in other folder from where I can fetch it.
I have given here code
save.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_POST['name'] .'"');

echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';

$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);


$return=file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);

?>
```

This is javascript function from where I am sending data to save.php

```
function capture(){
html2canvas($("#share"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");    
    $('#img_val').val(myImage);
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks mostly right, however, I think you're missing that there's some garbage characters you're going to need to strip out from your javascript `canvas.toDataURL()` call, namely spaces, which you'll have to convert to plus-signs. Otherwise it will corrupt your data, for example:

```
<?php
  $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$encodedData);
  $decocedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before sending an image as you have to encode it to prevent data corruption:

```
var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    myImage = encodeURIComponent(myImage);
```